# Connection Error TightVNC Server on Windows 10 Pro

Tags: networking, remote-desktop, tightvnc

I was wondering if anyone has had this problem before. I'm trying to connect to my Windows 10 machine via TightVNC. I have TightVNC server installed on the Windows machine and I'm sure that the firewall isn't blocking port 5800 (as I am using the Java applet to connect since I'm on a Mac).

I have tried connecting through exposing an ngrok endpoint on the Windows machine, and via the local IP address but in both cases it gets stuck at:

```
INFO: Handshaking with remote host
```

I'm certain that I have connected to the Windows machine via the logs, and the fact that when the handshaking is happening there is a connect live on the ngrok display.

I have also tried changing the port from 5800 to 5801, but I will get the same error.

The full log is below:

```
Jun 26, 2019 7:33:55 PM com.glavsoft.viewer.swing.SwingNetworkConnectionWorker doInBackground
INFO: Connecting to host 0.tcp.ngrok.io:18008
Jun 26, 2019 7:33:55 PM com.glavsoft.viewer.swing.ConnectionPresenter successfulNetworkConnection
INFO: Connected
Jun 26, 2019 7:33:55 PM com.glavsoft.viewer.swing.SwingRfbConnectionWorker doInBackground
INFO: Handshaking with remote host
Jun 26, 2019 7:35:11 PM com.glavsoft.viewer.swing.SwingRfbConnectionWorker done
SEVERE: Connection Error : java.io.EOFException, possible reason: remote host not responding.
```

Comment: Did you find a solution? For me, it's the same problem.